# LINQ and check for !=null

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Never used `LINQ` within C# before until 30 mins ago and am struggling to find an answer to my query online (probably due to my lack of understanding).

I have a simple query

```
var variableName = from a in tableName.AsEnumerable()
    where a.column1 == item1
        && a.column2 == item2
        && a.column3 != null
    select a;
```

The SQL column is defined as an int, null.

When the code encounters a record that is null on the database for `column3`, the following **error** is generated "`the value for column3 in table <tableName> is DBNull`".

Instead of checking for `!= null`, i guess i should be using something else, but have attempted checking for `DBNull`.Value but the compiler states "`Operation != cannot be applied to operands of type int and system.DBNull`".

Any ideas?

Comment: type of that column in db ?

Comment: Try changing the type of `a.column3` to the `Nullable int?`

Comment: what is `tableName` and `column3` here? is this a typed data-set for example? or...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a typed dataset, which : yeuch - *stop using those*, but I digress.

As such, accessing `a.column3` will always raise an exception if that value is `DBNull`. You would need to use the typed-dataset pattern:

```
&& !c.Iscolumn3Null()
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems to work.  I can successfully retrieve null and not null values.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Giraffe k, but please - for the love of all code, please please consider moving away from typed data-sets. Pretty please.

Comment: @Giraffe I just saw your comment to Marcin - indeed, if you are just changing one thing, then sure - maintain the existing code-base. But when doing something new, at least *consider* using a different tech ;p

Answer (score 0):

`tableName.AsEnumerable()` makes the query in-memory, so all table rows are downloaded from DB and the conditions are checked on application.

Try that:

```
var variableName = from a in tableName
                   where a.column1 == item1
                       && a.column2 == item2
                       && a.column3 != null
                   select a;
```

It should be translated into an SQL query and download only necessary rows.

Comment: to me, this "query" actually looks like a typed dataset, in which case this simply doesn't apply

Comment: Yes this is a typed dataset.  It's also code that's already in Production and this is a minor change, so I am not permitted to make any changes to the SQL table or to change the fundamental structure i.e. I have to use the LINQ code that is already present and just add the one line to check for != null.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var variableName = from a in tableName.AsEnumerable()
    where a.column1 == item1
        && a.column2 == item2
        && !DBNull.Value.Equals(a.column3)
    select a;
```

**edit** apparently I need to read up on typed data sets :) and why I should never use them

Comment: since accessing `a.column3` seems to have caused this error, I really doubt that will help

Comment: I only saw that the type mismatch was causing the issue... how do we know that simply accessing column3 is the error? from the doc: "To evaluate database fields to determine whether their values are DBNull, you can pass the field value to the DBNull.Value.Equals method. However, this method is rarely used because there are a number of other ways to evaluate a database field for missing data. These include the Visual Basic IsDBNull function, the Convert.IsDBNull method, the DataTableReader.IsDBNull method, the IDataRecord.IsDBNull method, and several other methods."

Comment: @mckeejm regular comparisons would not be specific about the column name, because that context is lost once the value is fetched; thus, the exception must be coming from **inside** the access to `a.column3` - which strongly suggests to me that this is a "typed dataset"

Comment: interesting... I'll look into that

Comment: Yes, "&& !DBNull.Value.Equals(a.column3)" still generates the error "The value for column <name> in table <name> is DBNull." Am just going to try Marc's suggestion now "&& !c.Iscolumn3Null()".

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var variableName = from a in tableName.AsEnumerable()
    where a.column1 == item1
        && a.column2 == item2
        && a.column3 != dbnull.value
    select a;
```

Comment: please see my reply to mckeejm - I strongly suspect that this error is happening inside the `a.column3` member-access, so it won't matter *what* we compare it to, since it won't ever get that far

Comment: As stated in my first post, this generates "Operation != cannot be applied to operands of type int and system.DBNull".

Comment: i am taking deep drive into this scenario.